# yum-complete-transaction in a crazy loop

Tags: linux, centos, bash, yum, update

I was trying to update a server that I have with `yum update` and it aborted because the server ran out of memory. I killed off a few processes that were not needed and ran `yum-complete-transaction` but it seems as though that's stuck in a crazy loop.

```
[root@syd-01 ~]# uname -a
Linux syd-01.*******.net 2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 16 18:37:12 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this. Below is an excerpt of the loop (it's much longer in reality):

```
--> Processing Dependency: libtinfo.so.5()(64bit) for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
---> Package net-tools.x86_64 0:1.60-110.el6_2 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: net-tools for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64 0:3.14.3-3.el6_4 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so()(64bit) for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so()(64bit) for package: p11-kit-trust-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so()(64bit) for package: p11-kit-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3)(64bit) for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3)(64bit) for package: p11-kit-trust-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3)(64bit) for package: p11-kit-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
---> Package nss-softokn-freebl.x86_64 0:3.14.3-10.el6_5 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so()(64bit) for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so()(64bit) for package: p11-kit-trust-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so()(64bit) for package: p11-kit-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3)(64bit) for package: glibc-2.12-1.132.el6_5.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3)(64bit) for package: p11-kit-trust-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3)(64bit) for package: p11-kit-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
---> Package p11-kit.x86_64 0:0.18.5-2.el6_5.2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3)(64bit) for package: p11-kit-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so()(64bit) for package: p11-kit-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
---> Package p11-kit-trust.x86_64 0:0.18.5-2.el6_5.2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so(NSSRAWHASH_3.12.3)(64bit) for package: p11-kit-trust-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/sbin/update-alternatives for package: p11-kit-trust-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /usr/sbin/update-alternatives for package: p11-kit-trust-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: p11-kit-trust-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: p11-kit-trust-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libfreebl3.so()(64bit) for package: p11-kit-trust-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.x86_64
---> Package pcre.x86_64 0:7.8-6.el6 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre.so.0()(64bit) for package: grep-2.6.3-4.el6_5.1.x86_64
---> Package popt.x86_64 0:1.13-7.el6 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: libpopt.so.0()(64bit) for package: grubby-7.0.15-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpopt.so.0()(64bit) for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpopt.so.0()(64bit) for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpopt.so.0(LIBPOPT_0)(64bit) for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpopt.so.0(LIBPOPT_0)(64bit) for package: grubby-7.0.15-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpopt.so.0(LIBPOPT_0)(64bit) for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
---> Package sed.x86_64 0:4.2.1-10.el6 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: sed for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: sed for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
---> Package shared-mime-info.x86_64 0:0.70-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: shared-mime-info-0.70-4.el6.x86_64
---> Package tar.x86_64 2:1.23-11.el6 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: tar for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
---> Package which.x86_64 0:2.19-6.el6 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: which for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
---> Package zlib.x86_64 0:1.2.3-29.el6 will be erased
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1()(64bit) for package: glib2-2.26.1-7.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1()(64bit) for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1()(64bit) for package: libxml2-2.7.6-14.el6_5.2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libz.so.1(ZLIB_1.2.2)(64bit) for package: glib2-2.26.1-7.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: initscripts-9.03.40-2.el6.centos.4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: iproute-2.6.32-32.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: udev-147-2.51.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.14.el6_5.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: grubby-7.0.15-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: grubby-7.0.15-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/bash for package: grubby-7.0.15-5.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: There is a specific package (or packages) it's choking on, which are at the _end_ of the output, but that output wasn't included here.

Comment: I had the same issue recently. The fix was to run the following commands: `sudo yum clean all`, `sudo rm -rf /var/cache/yum`, and `sudo yum-complete-transaction --cleanup-only`. After running these commands, `yum update` worked normally.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone that stumbles across this issue here is what I did to help in a similar situation.

```
yum clean all
package-cleanup  -y --cleandupes
yum-complete-transaction
yum distro-sync
yum update
```